# Stubbing ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, stubbing

Say I have a Company which may contain many employees of type Employee may contain many tasks of type Task.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base; has_many :employees; end
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base; belongs_to :company, has_many :tasks; end
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base; belongs_to :employee; end
```

Using tools like FactoryGirl I may be tempted to create tasks using `FactoryGirl.create(:task)` forcing an employee and a company to be created as well.

What I want to do is to create valid ActiveRecord objects but with their relationships stubbed out so as to make my tests faster.

A solution I came up is to not use FactoryGirl and create the new objects using mock_model/stub_model to stub their associations.

Example:

```
employee = mock_model(Employee)
task = Task.create! name: "Do that", employee: employee
```

Am I doing it right?

Thanks.

Comment: use FactoryGirl.build_stub

Comment: FactoryGirl.build_stubbed (not build_stub) worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to create anything in the database you can do this:

```
employee = mock_model(Employee)
task = mock_model(Task, name: "Do that", employee: employee)
```

Keep in mind that you can't query them like that. It's roughly the same as building the object.  If you ever want to do anything where you need to query actual data such as an integration test then you'll need use `create` to make stuff in the database. Or as one commenter pointed out, you can use FactoryGirl's methods to stub stuff out.

Answer (score 5):

There is a distinct difference between `mock_model` and `stub_model`.

Assuming you're using RSpec, check out [Mock Model](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/mocks/mock-model) and [Stub Model](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/mocks/stub-model).

Briefly though, the main difference is that `mock_model` is a true test double, that *acts* like an AR model. `stub_model` will create an instance of an *actual* AR model.

Either one of these options, along with Eric C's code snippet, is a good way to isolate your tests from the DB.